# Postgres UPDATE position of all items in table in INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE trigger

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am writing an app that has a kanban-style card view, similar to [Trello](https://trello.com/) or [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira).

- Cards exists in lists
- Cards can be drag-and-dropped re-ordered within a list
- Cards can be drag-and-dropped horizontally between lists.

**I am trying to write a Postgres trigger + procedure so that, on insert, update or delete, position values are updated to reflect the new ordering.**

I am a novice with postgres (and particularly with triggers/procedures) so I am a bit stuck on how to achieve this.

I have the following tables:

```sql
create table lists (
  id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  name text,
  
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table cards (
  id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  listId INT NOT NULL,
  content text,
  position INT,
  
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (listId) REFERENCES lists(id) 
);
```

When a `Card` is `DELETE`ed, `INSERT`ed or `UPDATE`ed with a given `position`, all the other `Card`s belonging to the same `List` must have their `position` updated to reflect the updated ordering.

i.e given the below data:

```
-- cards
| id | listId | content | position |
|----|--------|---------|----------|
| 1  | 1      | A       | 1        |
| 2  | 1      | B       | 2        |
| 3  | 1      | C       | 3        |
```

If I were to perform the following operation:

```sql
UPDATE cards SET position = 2 WHERE id = 3;
```

The final data should update like so:

```
-- cards
| id | listId | content | position |
|----|--------|---------|----------|
| 1  | 1      | A       | 1        |
| 3  | 1      | C       | 2        |
| 2  | 1      | B       | 3        |
```

I think I can accomplish this with a DB trigger and a procedure. The trigger will fire on `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, but I am not sure how the procedure should be written.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_order() 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
  -- how do I update the position field without triggering infinite loop?
COMMIT
END $$;

CREATE TRIGGER update_order
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON "cards"
    FOR EACH ROW WHERE listId = NEW.listId
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_order()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that triggers are not suitable for you due to the fact that this will cause an infinite loop. My suggestion is to create a regular function that needs to be called after every modification of the `cards` table. The function will update the `position` column from the `cards` table, sorting rows by column `position` and `modified` (you need to add).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_order() RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN 
with ordered_cards AS
(select *, row_number() over()  from (select *   from cards ORDER BY position, modified DESC) t)

update cards set position = ordered_cards.row_number from ordered_cards where cards.id = ordered_cards.id;
END
$$;
 
select update_order();
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=13772f1977222674ab2767c1a3b74ca0)